# Microsoft Excel: PowerPivot, how to translate sql query into a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerpivot

I have a select statement that works in my sql but I tried to use it in powerpivot but it does not work. This is the sql statement

```
SELECT sum((p.list_price-s.discount) * isnull(s.QuantitySold,0))
  FROM ProductDim p
  full join SalesFacts s on p.product_key = s.product_key
  group by Product_Name, Brand_Description, Category_Description, list_price;
```

So I translated it to this

```
=SUM((ProductDim[List_Price]-SalesFacts[Discount]) * SalesFacts[QuantitySold])
```

However, this does not work as I am receiving this error: The SUM function only accepts a column reference as an argument. Anyone is able to help with this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUMX(
 SalesFacts,
 (
   RELATED(ProductDim[List_Price])
   -SalesFacts[Discount]
 ) 
 * SalesFacts[QuantitySold]
)
```

If you want to do a row level calculation like this then `SUMX` will accomplish that.